# Custom code in expression with Microsoft Report Builder

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I'm having some trouble understanding how to use more complex Visual Basic in Microsoft Report Builder expressions. Is this even possible?

I have a report that accepts an array of account numbers, like "11111", "11112" and so on. I want to iterate over the IDs at runtime and set a particular to one value if a "special" ID is being requested, or set it to another value otherwise.

I've tried the following:

```
=IIF(InStr("11111", Join(Parameters!ClientID.Value, ",")), "Option One", "Option Two")
```

When only a single client ID is provided and that client ID is "special", I receive the expected value of "Option One" in cell. However, when multiple are provided, even when the "special" ID is still among those multiple values, I will instead receive "Option Two". hat leads me to believe that it is a problem with my Join statement, but I'm quite new to this and I'm not seeing any good way to debug or get a meaningful error message out of this.

My next thought was to flesh out my code by writing a visual basic function that will iterate over all of the array values received, and return true if the "special" value is among them. It looked like this:

```
  Public Function UseAlt(arr As String()) As Boolean
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    For Each id As String In arr
        If id = "11111" Then
            found = True
        End If
    Next
    Return found
  End Function
```

But it seems that you cannot put code like this in an expression, as far as I can tell. I did some searching around and found this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-code-to-a-report-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16

So I followed that and embedded the function detailed above in the report, and I attempted to call it like this in the expression:

```
=IIF(Code.UseAlt(Parameters!ClientID.Value), "Option One", "Option Two")
```

Unfortunately this results in displaying #Error in the cell. As I said before, I don't know how to debug this. I'm not getting a meaningful error message that even tells me what to do as far as I can tell.

Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong, or at least tell me how to properly debug these #Error errors?

**Update:**

I found another solution that is simple (shown below) and doesn't break when multiple IDs are provided, but my question still stands. Is it possible to use more complex visual basic in expressions or not? how do I properly debug the #Error errors in my cells?

```
=IIF(Join(Parameters!ClientID.Value, ",") Like "*11111*", "Option One", "Option Two")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is from memory so may not be perfect but I have done something like this in the past..

I use JOIN and .Contains something like

```
=IIF(("|" & JOIN(Parameters!ClientID.Value, "|") & "|").ToString().Contains("|11111|"), "Option One", "Option Two")
```

You might not need the leading and trailing `|` but I usually include them so that it's less ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that looks great too. Do you have any resources you might suggest? I would like to fully understand what is available to me, but I'm finding the documentation mostly confusing. I believe .ToString and .Contains are from .NET, so are all .NET methods available? Thanks.

Comment: Documentation is pretty poor in this area I found. I think you have access to all the core system .net methods (not .NET Core ;-) ) for strings maths and dates and for standard data types but it certainly is not a full set. It's not something I use a lot.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate the help!